# Apache directory permissions

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to build a web-server which will be used for collecting data via a series of forms. I would like to serve Apache content via the main users home directory so I have created a /www directory there - this will make life easier for launching new code and keep things tidier.

The problem I am facing is that I keep getting permission denied messages all the time, despite the fact that I have changed the owner/group for that directory to the one Apache is running. My guess is that I am seeing those messages since the parent directory, ie the users directory is not readable etc.

Is there any way to set this up so I don't compromise security of the users home directory yet still be able to have Apache read content from a directory is his home dir?

Thanks
S.

Comment: @wombie but is this secure? Isn't there an easier way to do this? I've also tried using symlinks to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Set the homedir with `o+x`, that'll allow Apache to traverse the homedir without being able to see what's inside it.